# Using MediaScannerConnection.scanFile() in a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-file, android-mediascanner

I am downloading a file from within a `Fragment` asynchronously and would like to call `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` when the download completes. I am able to get desired results if I sit and wait for the download to finish without navigating away from my Fragment (or its hosting activity). The problem I am facing is that `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` requires a context and I don't want to limit the user to staying within a `Fragment`/`Activity` just so that context is not null.

How do I make use of `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile()` in the background so that I can scan the files and display a `Toast` when the scanning is complete while still navigating in other parts of my app (or even tabbing out of my app)?

This is how I am currently scanning (with a context):

```
public static void mediaScanFile(Context context, String path) {
    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(context,
            new String[]{path}, null,
            new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                    Log.d("Tag", "Scan finished. You can view the image in the gallery now.");
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, downloading a file from a `Fragment` which may be destroyed soon is not a good idea. You should **use foreground service** instead.

---

If you still want to stick with fragments, in your case, you can make use of the application context.

Before starting the download, store a reference of the application context as a field in your fragment.

```
Context appContext;

// Inside onCreateView
appContext = getContext().getApplicationContext();
```

Then you can use the application context for scanning media.

This won't cause memory leak because the application context is a single shared instance and won't be destroyed until the app is killed.